# Three.js - get image dimensions and pass to fragment shader

Tags: three.js

I'm sending a bitmap as a uniform to a fragment shader with THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(). What's the simplest way for the fragment shader to access the size of the image in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the values you want to the shader as uniforms.

Comment: And what's the simplest way to get those values?

Comment: Assuming you have `texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()` then you can say `width = texture.image.width`